# Time complexity of Sieve of erastothenes

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I do not understand why there is no factor of √n in time complexity.
Here is the code

```py
def sieve_of_erastothenes(max):
    flags = [True] * (max+1)
    num = 2
    while num*num <= max:
        if flags[num] is True:  # if it is a prime number
            cross_off(flags, num)
        num += 1
    return [i for i in range(2,len(flags)) if flags[i] is True]


def cross_off(flags, prime):
    # no point in crossing anything before prime*prime
    for num in range(prime*prime, len(flags), prime):
        flags[num] = False
        num += prime
```

The outer loop (`num*num <= max`) runs for √n times. If flag has been set, inner loop runs for n/p times. Summation of n/p where p is only prime gives n*loglogn
So time complexity should be O(√n * n * loglogn). But everywhere I read, it is given as O(nloglogn)

Comment: The inner loop only runs when num is prime, so there is an additive sqrt(N) term, but you can drop it, because it's dominated by the N*loglog N.

Comment: The `n log log n` term is the total time for all the cross_ofs, not the time for a single call. Were it the time for a single call, you would need to multiply by the number of calls, but it isn't so you don't.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured it out with the help of comments from Matt Timmermans and rici. I had 2 misunderstandings

1. The inner loop for a given prime runs `n / prime` times.
   The summation n/2 + n/3 + n/5 + n/7 + n/11 .... is already taking into account the outer √n factor. The summation itself is *because* of the outer loop.
2. The failure case of if condition *IS* being counted, but it is being overpowered by the other factor. So we can write it as,

```
num => 2     3     4   5     6   7     8   9   10  11
sum => n/2 + n/3 + 1 + n/5 + 1 + n/7 + 1 + 1 + 1 + n/11...

sum => (n/2 + n/3 + n/5 ...) + (1 + 1 + 1 + 1....)
sum => (nloglogn) + (n)    #  Worst case. 1+1+1.. will always be less than n
```

O(nloglogn + n) = O(nloglogn)